# Git pull fatal error[could not read remote repository]

Tags: git, ssh, openshift, ssh-keys, git-bash

I want pull and push my code to openshift.
I am using Gitbash.
When i pull i got error:

```
$ git pull
fatal: '~/git/app.git/' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

How to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your remote named origin doesn't reference the opehshift repo.
Type:

```
git remote -v
```

If the url of the remote repo is wrong, change it with:

```
git remote set-url origin /url/openshift/repo
```

See also "[Using the Git Repository](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-overview.html#_using_the_git_repository)" of the [Getting Started with OpenShift Online](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-overview.html) doc for `rhc` specific commands.